# ajaxcontroltoolkit Accordion pane change event

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, accordion

I am trying to capture the event when the user click on a new pane of Accordion.
I thought can use the OnItemCommand, so I used like this :

```
  <asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"  CssClass="accordion"  
                    HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"   
                    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"  
                    ContentCssClass="accordionContent" Width="400px"  OnItemCommand="Accordion1_ItemCommand">
```

and also code behind like this :

```
 protected void Accordion1_ItemCommand(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

            Label1.Text = "Accordion is clicked";
        }
```

but when I run , nothing is happening ! Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work that way i guess.
You can try to do as follows:
Add asp:LinkButton control to your Panel's header and add OnClick event to it. Then stretch LinkButton to all header width and adjust styles.

```
<asp:Accordion ID="Accordion1" runat="server"  CssClass="accordion"  
                HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"   
                HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"  
                ContentCssClass="accordionContent" Width="400px">
   <Panes>  
       <asp:AccordionPane ID="AccordionPane1" runat="server">  
          <Header>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="HyperLink1" runat="server"  OnClick="HyperLink1_Click" Text="Pane 1"></asp:LinkButton>
         </Header>  
         <Content>  
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.  Maecenas porttitor congue massa. Fusce posuere, magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero, sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.  
    Nunc viverra imperdiet enim. Fusce est. Vivamus a tellus.  
    Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pharetra nonummy pede. Mauris et orci.              
         </Content>  
     </asp:AccordionPane>   
   </Panes>  
 </asp:Accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to set Suppress Header Postbacks to get a link or button to work on an Accordion Header (depending if you want the accordion open item to change or not when the button or link is selected).

```
    <asp:Accordion ID="MyMenu" runat="Server" AutoSize="None"
        FadeTransitions="true" TransitionDuration="250" FramesPerSecond="20" RequireOpenedPane="false"
        SuppressHeaderPostbacks="true">
    </asp:Accordion>
```